# Python3: Multiple global vars

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with global vars but I get the error "NameError: name 'second_global_var' is not defined"

```
def my_function():
    global first_global_var, second_global_var
    if(first_global_var or second_global_var):
        pass
```

Why it shows the error for 'second_global_var' and not for 'first_global_var', even if I define them each one with in its own line with global, the error persist for the variable 'second_global_var'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `global` statement does not create variables.  It just makes Python look for them in the global namespace instead of the local namespace.  In other words, saying `global some_name` tells Python to look for a global variable called `some_name` whenever you try to refer to `some_name`.

If that variable doesn't exist when you try to use it, Python will raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the interpreter, you have:

```
   >>> def my_function():
    ...     global first_global_var, second_global_var
    ...     if(first_global_var or second_global_var):
    ...         pass
    ...
```

Then calling the function:

```
>>> my_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in my_function
NameError: global name 'first_global_var' is not defined
```

It complains about the first variable that it is not defined.